# Why I rewrite my properties file into yaml file with same content but then spring project throws an error?

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I wrote a simple spring project with `spring-data-jpa` dependency and it ran pretty well with `application.properties` with content below:

```
spring.application.name=customer-service
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hat
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
```

But after I rewrite it into yaml file `application.yaml`:

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hat
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    data-username: root
    data-password: 
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: false
```

My project throws an error

```
Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
```

I'm so sure that I'v put these files into correct place and only used one at a time.

Shouldn't these two files have same content? I'm so confused...

Comment: Seems like your not added the 'hibernate.dialect' parameter either of the properties file, like this : spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = type of dialect ?

Comment: @DelliKilari but my project ran well with `application.properties` file, and it doesn't work even if I add this with yaml format into yaml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of typos in your YAML so the files aren’t equivalent. You have `username` and `password` in the properties file but `data-username` and `data-password` in the YAML.

This misconfiguration means that Hibernate cannot connect to the database to detect the dialect that it should use. As a result it required the dialect to be configured instead.

I believe you can fix the problem by correcting the YAML:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hat
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    username: root
    password: 
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: false
```

Comment: thank you seems like autocomplete led me to wrong word